# how to compartmentalize a big graph using twopi

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

I have a rather large graph in DOT, which I render using *neato*
and I'm more or less able to distinguish its main clusters using a lot of `len=...` attributes.

I wanted to experiment with *twopi*, because I like a lot the way it renders, but I see that it doesnt support `len`.

There are alternatives? My need is to manually keep some portions of the graph rather isolated from others, to enhance readability. I tried with clusters but apparently the results are not so good.

Answer (score 0):

With `twopi`, you specify a [root](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:root) then the number of edges away from root will dictate which ring of the circle it belongs on.  Another alternative you might also consider is `circo` which is yet another graphing tool from graphviz.